# get document with fields (and no value) present in other documents

Tags: python, mongodb

suppose you have a collection with 2 documents :

```
{ 'name' : 'lutin1', 'mood' : 'good', 'last_say' : 'hello you' }
{ 'name' : 'lutin2', 'mood' : 'great' 'title' : 'mayor' }
```

we use the great no-schema feature of mongodb.
but if i need to show content:

```
for user in users:
    print("{n} said : {s}".format(n=user['name'], s=user['last_say']))
```

will give a 'no key error' for 'lutin2'
one way is to test each time if key is present, but if your documents have much more fields, it increases your code in big proportion.

the simpliest solution would be to have, for each document, all possible fields found in the collection. 
in this case, all document would have 4 fields (name, mood, title, last_say) with null value when a particuliar fields is not present (as any SQL DB work)
does mongoDB provide such an option ?

if not, how would you cope with this issue ?

thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store null's for every field. Use [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to handle such situations. Pass the default value as a second argument.

How your code should looks like:

```
for user in users:
    print("{n} said : {s}".format(n=user['name'], s=user.get('last_say', 'Nothing!')))
```